# Visual Studio code Python not intalled

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm just installed Visual Studio Code yesterday and am getting the error that Python is not installed.   I currently have Python 3.8 installed.  I have tried installed Python 3.7 and Python 3.5 and still am getting the same error that python is not installed and am unable to select a python interpreter even when I point it to directory of my python install.

Comment: You run code by VS Code or command line ?

Comment: Are both VS code and Python both use the same processor configuration? So are they both 32 OR 64-bit?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your setup and the error message?

Comment: Did you check the [windows environment path variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616399/windows-anaconda-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the "Visual Studio Code and the Python Extension" installed. (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

You could try replacing the path slashes with double back-slashes. 
See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3460#issuecomment-452708017

For example:
`C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe`

Comment: I have tried this and it still is not working.  I did install my python on the root of C.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by uninstalling Python, then reinstalling to a simpler path.

My previous installation was located at: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe` so I reinstalled Python to `C:\python` and VS Code now recognizes the interpreter.

> It also warned me that I was using an outdated version of PIP (even
> though I installed the latest Python version - `3.8.5`), but it was
> easily upgraded by typing the installation command provided in the
> error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine solved by removing the .vscode folder and the vscode config file. Now everything seems to be working fine

If you are on Linux then run these commands:

```
rm ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json
rm -rf ~/.config/Code
rm -rf ~/.vscode
```

Then if you want you can reinstall vscode, mine worked without a need to reinstall

Answer (score -2):

It's simple just go to the extension tab and type "Python". Install the First one (By Microsoft) and restart vs code and your good to go.