why creating a conda environment with a specific python version does not lead the env to have this version?
I have a big issue with conda and python, I cannot find a solution anywhere
I did this:
conda create --name myenv python=3.9

then
conda activate myenv

then, I typed python and I got

Any idea why it's not working ?
[UPDATE for answering the first comment]

[UPDATE 2]


Did you run the conda init command? I think the problem is that your terminal is still looking for the version of Python that is installed outside ot conda. If you use bash,  you can run conda init bash. After restarting the terminal, you should now be able to correctly activate an environment and run its own Python version.

@ThePunisher thanks for the suggestion but I just tested and it still does not work, see my post update

Thanks for the update! Can you verify if you are using bash just in case? You can do this by running echo $0 in a terminal. Please, paste here the output of that command.

@ThePunisher I think yes, you can see the new update of my post, thanks

I see you are using Windows. The issue might be related to the Path environment variable not pointing to Anaconda. Please, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616915/6279885, and remember to restart your terminal after applying the environment variable changes!

I am not using windows, this is in a container.... but thanks

Can you run type python, I suspect you have an alias set up. Can you also share echo $PATH?

Also, if this is reproducible with a dockerfile, please share a minimal example here
